# How can you access the Value property of a CommandLine Parsed<T>?

Tags: c#, command-line-parser

How can you access the Value property of a CommandLine Parsed ?

Trying to use the [CommandLineParser](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline)

The wiki section on [Parsing](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline/wiki#parsing) says the instance of T can be access through the `Value` property ... 
*If parsing succeeds, you'll get a derived Parsed type that exposes an instance of T through its Value property.*

But I can't see any `Value` property on the `parserResult`, only a `Tag` ...

```
ParserResult<Options> parserResult = Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args);
WriteLine(parserResult.Tag);
```

And I know I'm missing something as if I debug, I can see the `Value` property ???

Comment: I'm guessing you need to cast and then you have the value [here](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline/blob/master/src/CommandLine/ParserResult.cs#L109).

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thanks for responding, but could you give actual code, as I'm not understanding how ???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get to parsed object (or errors in case parsing failed), you can do this:

```
ParserResult<Options> parserResult = Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args);
if (parserResult.Tag == ParserResultType.Parsed) {
    var options = ((Parsed<Options>)parserResult).Value;
}
else {
    var errors = ((NotParsed<Options>)parserResult).Errors;
}
```

That's questionable design, but in general you are not expected to do it like this anyway, expected usage is more like:

```
Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args)
  .WithParsed(options => ...)
  .WithNotParsed(errors => ...)IEnumerable<Error>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, that wasn't obvious for me neither!